# React-Router Routes Behaving Strangely

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm trying to run a book example that features a movies store. I've got the page to pull up and look right. The trouble is, when I click on a movie image nothing happens (the react-router is supposed to show an info box about the selected movie). My start URL is: 
http://localhost/~johndoe/react-dir/test-webpack/

When I click on a movie image nothing happens and the address bar changes to: 
http://localhost/movies/1

The Chrome dev tools, console says: 
browser.js:49 Warning: [react-router] Location "/movies/1" did not match any routes

My routes.js file is:

```
const React = require('react');
const {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} = require('react-router');
const App = require('components/app/app.js');
const Movies = require('components/movies/movies.js');
const Movie = require('components/movie/movie.js');
module.exports = (
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path={"/~johndoe/react-dir/test-webpack/"} component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Movies}/>
        <Route path={"movies"} component={Movies}>
            <Route path={":id"} component={Movie}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
);
```

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong? I'm not sure what to look for to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your source code or, ideally, create a simplified, stripped down version on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/new

Comment: https://pm04m0r2r0.codesandbox.io/
and
https://codesandbox.io/s/pm04m0r2r0
I'm unfamiliar with codesandbox.io but hopefully that will show you what I'm working with.  Any suggestions would be welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: I'll take a deeper look at it later tonight. In the meantime, do me a favor and change all of your `const example = require('../path/to/example')` statements to `import example from '../path/to/example'` or  `import { example } from '../path/to/example'`

Comment: I made the changes.  Thank you for looking at this.  I'm hoping to learn more about how react-router really works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright took a bit to deconstruct what was going on, but here's a working version.

**What's was going wrong**:

- You can't map over an undefined object or array. You need conditional rendering to check if the item is empty -- I used [lodash's isEmtpy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEmpty) as it makes life simpler over: `array && array.length > 0` for arrays and/or `Object.entries(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object` for objects. Without conditional rendering, when you clicked on the link, you were essentially breaking your app.

**What I changed**:

- Added conditional rendering using lodashes `isEmpty`. If the `movies` or `movie` value isn't present yet, it'll show a `Loading...` or `null` element.
- Utilized `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` lifecycles. Since React 16+, `componentWillMount` and `componentWillUpdate` have been deprecated and aren't recommended.
- Moved to Babel ES6 `import` and `export` statements -- can't think of a reason to use `module.exports` over `import` and `export`, especially if you're using babel to transpile your code. Now-a-days, you'll more than likely find the two bundled in a boilerplate. That said, you're more than welcome to make your life harder and not use `babel`. :)
- I don't particularly like `redux-actions` as it obscures what's going on with `redux` and its `store`. So I separated everything out into `actions`, `reducers`, and `types`.

I find it easier to understand the flow (the circle of life):

- Within a `connect`ed component, a user clicks an element (like a button), which triggers the `action`.
- The `action` returns a `type` and a `payload` to the `reducer`.
- The `reducer` matches against the `type` and shallow merges the `payload`
  into the reducer `state`.
- The component that is `connect`ed to redux accepts the new reducer `state` as `props`.

**Issues you'll have with your current setup:**

- Using strings as imports will not work when your application is bundled. They'll resolve to directories that no longer exist. It's recommended that you either serve the images ([like a CDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323381/image-returned-from-rest-api-always-displays-broken/52324048#52324048) -- check out the JSON `movie.cover` in the codesandbox for examples) or [import them directly into the file that requires them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378481/importing-an-image-into-an-src-tag-in-react-js-when-the-image-name-is-not-know/54385707#54385707).
- If a user tries to go directly to `movies/:id`, it'll break the application as `movies` wouldn't be currently defined in your `redux` state. As such, instead of using routing to showcase the details, I'd recommend using React's local `state` to pop out and hide the detail view based upon which movie was clicked.

**Recommended**:

- Your dependencies are fairly outdated. Unless absolutely necessary, I'd suggest upgrading `react` and `react-dom` from 15.2 to 16.x. and upgrading from react-router 2.6 to `react-router-dom` or at the very least to `react-router` v3+.
- If you're looking for a more up-to-date boilerplate, I'd recommend my [Webpack-React-Boilerplate](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Webpack-React-Boilerplate).

**Working example**: https://codesandbox.io/s/nk715xpqv4 (the codesandbox CRA template doesn't support CSS modules, so I had to import the styles and use the `className` as a string, but that doesn't mean you need to for your project).

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do that.  I'm trying to learn React from Manning's React Quickly (https://www.manning.com/books/react-quickly).  I guess it's outdated now.  I had never heard of Lodash but I'll try to use it.  What do you recommend for learning React the right way?

Comment: I'd recommend investing some time and money into this course: https://www.udemy.com/react-2nd-edition/. If you wait, you'll usually find it on sale for around $10.