# Merging Images Using Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, image-processing

I am creating a website in which each user has an "avatar". An avatar has different accessories like hats, facial expressions, etc. I have made this previously on a php website but I am using react to create this new website. I am loading in each users avatar and its item links from firestore. I do not want to 
use absolute positioning or css, I want the avatar to be one image.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I found this library: https://github.com/lukechilds/merge-images which seems to be exactly what I need but I cannot load in external images or I get this error:

[image: error img]

Any solutions to this error or suggestions to an alternative would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
render() {

mergeImages([
  'http://example.com/images/Avatar.png',
  'http://example.com/images/Hat.png',
])
.then((b64) => {
  document.querySelector('img.abc').src = b64;
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
return (
  ...
      <img class="abc" src='' width={100} height={200} alt="avatar"/>
  ...
); }
```

Comment: are the images coming from a different domain than yours? that's probably what's happening

Comment: Yes they would be coming from a different domain, most likely firebase cloud storage. In these tests though I am just using random images from other sites. This is one of the main difficulties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `merge-images` package has some quirks. One of those quirks is that it expects individual images to either be served from your local server (example: `http://localhost:3000/images/head.png`, `http://localhost:3000/images/eyes.png`, and `http://localhost:3000/images/mouth.png`) **or** that those individual images be imported into a single file.

**Working example**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example (this example includes the first three options explained below with the fourth option utilizing the end result of using a third party CDN)

To run the example, clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example
```

Change directory:

```
cd merge-images-example
```

Then install dependencies:

```
yarn install
```

Then run the development server:

```
yarn dev
```

**Option 1**:
The simplest implementation would be to import them into a [AvatarFromFiles](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/components/AvatarFromFiles/index.js#L3-L5) component. However, as written, it isn't reusable and isn't suitable for dynamically selected avatars.

**Option 2**:
You may want to serve them from the local server like the [AvatarFromLocalServer](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/components/AvatarFromLocalServer/index.js#L11-L13) component with a [Webpack Dev Config](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/config/devServer.js#L25-L27). Then you would retrieve [stored strings](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/pages/Home/index.js#L10) from an [API](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/pages/Home/index.js#L19-L28) and [pass them down into from state into the component](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/pages/Home/index.js#L52). Once again, this still requires the images to be present in the `images` folder, but more importantly, it isn't ideal for a production environment because the `images` folder [must be placed outside](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/server.js#L12) of the `src` folder to be served. This could also lead to security issues. Therefore, I don't recommend this option at all.

**Option 3:**
Same as Option 1, but lazy loaded like the [AvatarFromLazyFiles](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/components/AvatarFromLazyFiles/index.js#L11-L13) component and therefore flexible. You can load images by their [name](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/pages/Home/index.js#L11); however, it still requires that all of the images be present upon runtime and during production compilation. In other words, what you have on hand is what you get.

**Option 4**:
So... the ideal option would be to build an [image microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324048/7376526) or use a [CDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CDN) that handles all things images (uploading, manipulating/merging, and serving images). The client would only be able to select/upload new images to this microservice/CDN, while the microservice/CDN handles everything else. This may require a bit more work but offers the [most flexibility](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/pages/Home/index.js#L16), [super easy](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/pages/Home/index.js#L54) to [implement](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/merge-images-example/blob/master/src/components/AvatarFromCDN/index.js#L7), and best performance -- as it offloads all the work from the client to the dedicated service.

In conclusion, unless you plan on having a set amount of images, use option 3, otherwise option 4.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great. Unfortunately option 4 is not quite feasible for my current structure but I made it work with Lazy Loading like you showed in the example.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

This is a CORS issue. The images are coming from a different origin that's not your server.

If you look at the [source of the library](https://github.com/lukechilds/merge-images/blob/master/src/index.js#L35-L69), you'll notice it's using a `<canvas>` under the hood to merge the images, and then getting the resulting data. Canvas cannot work with images loaded from another domain. There's good [reasoning behind this](https://simonsarris.com/understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules/). In essence, loading an image into a canvas is a way to fetch data, and since you can retrieve the data from the canvas as base64, a malicious one could steal information by first loading it into a `<canvas>` and then pulling it out.

You can read about it directly from the [spec for the `<canvas>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#security-with-canvas-elements).

### Solution

You need to serve the images either from the same origin (essentially, the same domain) or include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ...` on the HTTP headers that serve the images. There's ways to do this [in firebase storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760695/firebase-storage-and-access-control-allow-origin), or other server solutions you might use.

Comment: It is indeed a CORS issue. Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't seem to work when I try everything in that thread you referenced.

Comment: Huh. Did you confirm the images are being served with a lax `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? You can check in the Network tab on the browser.

Edit: just noticed you commented above that you got it working. Happy to hear!