# How to import the image dynamically

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, urlloader

I use url-loader to load images in my webpage by converting them in byte.

Here is my normal case which works fine:

```
import React from 'react';
import accountImg from '../../../../images/setting/account.png';
const Account =(props) => (
<div>
    <img src={accountImg} className="img-responsive" style={{"width":"100%"}} ></img>
</div>
 );
export default Account;
```

But what if I need a dynamic import:

```
    render() {
    return (
               <img  src={ "/images/headers/"+this.props.newsChannel.removeAllSpaces().toLowerCase()+".png"}></img>

    );
```

So specifically for this case:

```
src={ "/images/headers/"+this.props.newsChannel.removeAllSpaces().toLowerCase()+".png"
```

How can I import the png dynamically?

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1:** [Lazy load](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/) the images from within a reusable `class component`. You can load images by their `name` and a relative path to your `images` folder from this `component`; however, it still requires that all of the **images be present upon runtime and during production compilation**. In other words, what you have in your `images` folder is what you're stuck using.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class LazyLoadImage extends Component {
  state = { src: '', err: '' };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.loadImage();
  };

  loadImage = async () => {
    try {
      const { default: src } = await import(/* webpackMode: "lazy" */ `../../images/headers/${this.props.name}.png`);
      this.setState({ src });
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ err: err.toString() });
    }
  }; 

  render = () => (
    <Fragment>
      <h5>Lazy Load Images</h5>
      <img src={this.state.src} alt="example.png" />
      {this.state.err && <p>{this.state.err} </p>}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

LazyLoadImage.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default LazyLoadImage;
```

**Option 2:** The ideal option would be to build an image microservice or use a CDN that handles all things images. All that you would need to do is store a link to the image, for example, you'd store a `string` like: `http://localhost:4000/uploads/image.ext` (if you use a CDN, it'd be something like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq10x.png). The client would retrieve this `string` (from a database) and make a `GET` request to this link (when a HTTP `string` is added to an `img` element's `src` property -- `<img src="http://example.com/img.png" />` -- it automatically makes a `GET` request to that address).

This offers the most flexibility because you can add/remove/substitute images very easily by simply changing this string (it also doesn't need to be in your `images` folder to be loaded); it also offers the best performance -- [as it offloads all the image work from the client to the dedicated service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323381/image-returned-from-rest-api-always-displays-broken/52324048#52324048).

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ImageFromCDN = ({ src }) => (
  <Fragment>
    <h5>Image From CDN</h5>
    <img src={src} alt="example.png" />
  </Fragment>
);

ImageFromCDN.propTypes = {
  src: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default ImageFromCDN;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be use redux/context to wrap your Account function component with new states and change image src realtime

Comment: Can you explain more with an example?

Comment: when you pass newChannel prop to component this cannot be changed in render
you shoud use state store management like redux to dispatch your new value and get them in render realtime.